# Simple steps to Authenticate and do a query using c# and BigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

What are the Simple steps to Authenticate and do a query using c# and BigQuery.Any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to start would be here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/

The documentation is pretty sufficient to get you started, all API code samples are in Java which should make sense.

As for C#, I direct you to another question that contains working samples to Authenticate. We have not yet needed to query programatically as yet though.

[Google OAuth2 Service Account Access Token Request gives 'Invalid Request' Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939026/google-oauth2-service-account-access-token-request-gives-invalid-request-respo)